# Mongo update all records with a field that's null

Tags: mongodb

How do I update all Mongo documents that have a single field set to 'null', or that doesn't have a value at all?

What I have, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
db.collection.update({name: {$eq: null}}, {$set: {name: 'test'}})
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the name field is not there try:

```
db.collection.update({"name": {"$exists": false}}, {"$set": {"name": "test"}})
```

[**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior) will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint.

If it is there and null, or does not have a value set:

```
db.collection.update({"name": null}, {"$set": {"name": "test"}})
```

---

You can combine both queries using **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** as

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        "$or": [
            { "name": { "$exists": false } }, 
            { "name": null }
        ]
    }, 
    { "$set": { "name": "test" } }
)
```

---

For MongoDB 3.2 and above, use [**`updateMany()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db.collection.updateMany) which updates multiple documents within the collection based on the filter:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {
        "$or": [
            { "name": { "$exists": false } }, 
            { "name": null }
        ]
    }, 
    { "$set": { "name": "test" } }
)
```

Comment: You can use `$or` instead of writing two different queries

Comment: But @Michael, isn't `db.collection.find({ "$or": [ { "name": { "$exists": false } }, { "name": null } ] })` the same as just `db.collection.find({"name": null})`?

Comment: No it is not the same. `db.collection.find({"name": null})` will return doc only if  `name` exists and is `null`.

Comment: where would you add the {multi: true} to update multiple records

Comment: From the [**docs**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#definition) update takes the form `db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)` so `{multi: true}` option is placed after the update object.

Comment: If want to update all documents then use `updateMany` instead of update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: {'$or': [{'name': {$eq: null}}, {'name': {"$exists":false}},{ field: { "$type" : 10} }]},
    update: {$set: {name: 'test'}},
});
```

Thanks