# MongoDB - Update a field only if it doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258296/mongo-update-all-records-with-a-field-thats-null) similar to mine regarding updating a document if a certain field does not exist. But in the question, it is not an array of documents like what I have

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c144"),
"sender_id" : "123",
"iso_number" : "ABC-DEF-123",
"subject" : "Sample Memo",
"content" : "This is a sample memorandum sent through postman.",
"recipients" : [ 
    {
        "faculty_number" : 222,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c146"),
        "status" : "Sent"
    }, 
    {
        "faculty_number" : 111,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c145"),
        "status" : "Sent"
    }
],
"memo_created" : ISODate("2018-01-17T17:00:52.104Z"),
"__v" : 0                                                             
}
```

I'm trying to attach a memo_seen to recipient with faculty_number 111, I'm using the query.

```
db.getCollection('memos').update({"_id": id, "recipients.faculty_number": faculty_number, "recipients.$.memo_seen": {$exists: false}}, {$set: {"recipients.$.memo_seen": timestamp}})
```

The timestamp should not update when I repeat the query. Can someone help me out? Been stuck for quite some time now.

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('memos').update({"_id": id, "recipients:{$elemMatch:{ "faculty_number":faculty_number, "memo_seen": {$exists: false}}}}, {$set: {"recipients.$.memo_seen": timestamp}})`

Comment: Still the same, it updated the timestamp

Comment: It will not. Also, there is a typo in my query not sure how it ran for you. You may have multiple matching documents with each being updated every time. Correct query : `db.getCollection('memos').update({"_id": id, "recipients":{$elemMatch:{ "faculty_number":faculty_number, "memo_seen": {$exists: false}}}}, {$set: {"recipients.$.memo_seen": timestamp}})`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to put the exists condition inside elemMatch. It worked thank you!